# Is there a collaborative email program targeted to corporate communications departments?

Tags: email, collaboration, workflow, communication

We have a communications team that needs to share a mailbox on both PC and mobile devices. They have been using a common Exchange account and Outlook with a shared password but we've made an effort to tighten security lately and remove any usage of shared passwords.

We created a shared mailbox in Exchange but it lacks a couple of key features - most importantly being able to see who you BCC from a shared account and being able to access it easily on mobile devices.

I'm really looking for something like SharePoint publishing pages, but for email. Other features I'm looking for:

- Precise control over formatting, fonts, graphics, etc
- Multiple people should be able to access a common "drafts" area that's synchronized across computers and devices
- Drafts should have version control
- Should be able to send the email directly from the software to a large distribution group or individuals
- Record should be kept of all email sent and who was carbon copied and blind carbon copied - this info should be visible to all users on the team
- An approval system should be available but not required so that a finished draft can be routed for approval and then automatically sent
- Emails should be able to be scheduled, so they will be sent at a specified date and time in the future (if finalized and approved)
- Mobile interface for basic authoring, approving, scheduling and sending of email as well as reviewing what's been sent
- Works through Exchange (on premise) or Office 365 mail servers
- Preferably a "fat" client and a mobile app rather than a web interface for either platform

With all the corporate communications departments in the world, there must be a more specialized program than Outlook to craft, send, track and archive email collaboratively, right?

Comment: What version of outlook/exchange are you on? My work is hosted via MS, we have virtual accounts - I log in as myself to the outlook web client (OWA), change the URL to point to the other mailbox.  Once I'm in there, drafts are all same-same, sent is same-same, filters, out of office messages, etc.  I'm not a big fan of MS, but I think your current software could possibly do more of what you want.  Note that using Outlook does work BUT sent/drafts/etc stay on the original account/machine - you need to use the web client for this to work

Comment: We're on 2013. I think Outlook works decently well but am surprised that there's no dedicated communications software out there. Companies like Constant Contact or others will do this for customer communications and the value is obvious there but there's also value in tracking and managing internal communications, right?

Comment: That is mostly done with ticketing systems, but I think those will only hit a couple of your wants list.

Comment: Like Help Desk systems you mean?

Comment: Yes, like for a help desk or issue tracker

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for more of a collaborative email drafting system combined with a tracking system for follow up after the fact, you know? Basically what every corporate communications department does.